# Aurelia ui-virtualization infinite-scroll-next function not being hit after data refresh

Tags: aurelia, ui-virtualization

I'm using aurelia's `ui-virtualization` library to create a table using `virtual-repeat` and `infinite-scroll-next`.  Html looks something like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
       ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr virtual-repeat.for="item of items" infinite-scroll-next="getMore">
            ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This works great, except I have certain ui components and interactions that update what is in my `list` array.  Once that has be updated, the `infinite-scroll-next` function (`getMore()`) is never called.  I update something like this:

```
update() {
    let vm = this;
    vm.apiService.getData(vm.filterOption)
        .then(response => {
            vm.items = response.content.items;
        });
}
```

Where `filterOptions` are changed through the ui and `apiService.getData()` returns a promise from an http call. The data in the table updates correctly, but the infinite scroll is then broken.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in `ui-virtualization`?

**Edit:**

It appears there are some properties added to the array `__array_observer__` and `__observers__`.  Thinking overwriting the whole array and thus removing these properties might be causing the problem, I tried an approach where I just add or remove elements appropriately.  This does not work either.

**Edit:**

It seems to fail if I leave fewer than 7 of the original elements in the array.

Comment: I filed a bug with `aurelia-ui-virtualization` here: https://github.com/aurelia/ui-virtualization/issues/103